CellMix package can't be installed
I am currently trying to install the cellmix package in R version 4.3.2, and nothing is working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!
I have ran several lines of code:
> install_github("r-forge/cellmix/pkg/CellMix")
I got this error:
ERROR: dependencies ‘csSAM’, ‘BiocInstaller’ are not available for package ‘CellMix’
And this warning:
Warning messages: 1: packages ‘BiocInstaller’, ‘csSAM’ are not available for this version of R 
I have also tried to install using author methods, but they also gave similar error messages.
Third, I tried using
install.packages("BiocManager") BiocManager::install("cellmix") 
I got bascially the same message for all of them, saying that "Versions of these packages for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages" and I also looked on this page, and nothing helped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

I strongly encourage you to update R.
